# Penalized interpolation in python or matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I have a Loss function L and 2 signals f(t),g(t) .
I would like to find the function `s`  that minimize:  `L(f(t)-g(t+s(t)))+lambda*integral(s''(t))`

Ideally the `s` should be a polynomial or a spline.

Here the code I have written to start the problem:

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
import sklearn as sk
import scipy as sp
import scipy.io
from matplotlib.pyplot import * 
from scipy.interpolate import *

#mat = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/luca/Documents/phd_python_code/peak_aligment/john_example.mat')
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('../peak_aligment/john_example.mat')

t1=mat["t1"].squeeze()
t2=mat["t2"].squeeze()
t3=mat["t3"].squeeze()
t=sort(unique(concatenate((t1,t2,t3),axis=0)))
t_min=max(min(t1),min(t2),min(t3))
t_max=min(max(t1),max(t2),max(t3))
t=[val for val in t if t_min<=val<=t_max]
sig1=mat["sig_1"].squeeze()
sig2=mat["sig_2"].squeeze()
sig3=mat["sig_3"].squeeze()

s1=interp1d(t1,sig1,kind="cubic")
s2=interp1d(t2,sig2,kind="cubic")
s3=interp1d(t3,sig3,kind="cubic")
```

EDIT:
I am closer to the solutions but I am still having problems.

I defined a cost function:

```
def lost_function(p):
    pt=polyval(p,t)

    return norm(s1(t)-s2(pt))/len(index)
```

And I am trying to minimize it using scipy.optimize.minize. 
the main problem is that often `pt` is outside the range value of `t`. So when I call `s2(pt) i` receive an error. How can I interpolate the function also outside the range of t?

Comment: shouldn't be an `integral` before `L(f(t)-g(t+s(t)))` as well? also, are `f(t)` and `g(t)` analytic functions or given at finite set of points?

Comment: You could try Scipy's spline interpolation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation) - it also has smoothing. If you want to dive deeper into the topic, you might want to look at http://scikit-learn.org

Comment: @behzad.nouri The integral is only on the last part. This is a modified version of GAM (generalized additive models).  At the beginning the f and g where vector but I have interpolated with interp1d so now they are functions.

Comment: @Dietrich I use sklearn very often but  I did not find anything of useful in this case. Do you have any advices?

Comment: @Dietrich Oops, I  just saw your ``g()``, so its not a standard generalized linear model problem as originally thought. Now that I think about, it looks quite unusal. No chance on bringing it to standard form (maybe by a Fourier Transform)?

Comment: I am not working anymore in this problem but I have been able to solve a similar one using PSO algorithm. Hope it can help